# Samba force port

Tags: samba, network-share, ubuntu-14.04

I have a file server Running Samba here at my company.

Half of the computers are Macs and it is very slow to connect to Samba from OS X.

But I found out that if I force connection through port 139 (smb://sambaserver:139) the speed is significantly improved.

I wondering how can I force every connection to go through this port but not having to ask every user to update the configuration.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can influence this without touching the macs. But here are some other thoughts.

I found that connecting to `cifs://server/share` provides better service than using `smb://...`.

Also samba is getting osx fixes every now and then. So make sure you use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by remapping port 139 to 445. Do it for all hosts, or just for the ones with a Mac MAC ( ;) ).